# How to use Interlocked Method in overlapping multi-thread cumulative Stopwatch variable

Tags: c#, async-await, interlocked, parallel.for, interlocked-increment

I have a `stopwatch` embedded in my progress reporting under the hoods of `async/await`, `task. run()`, and `parallel. for`. The stopwatch captures the duration between the process and the cumulative duration as well.

I checked my code with `MessageBox.Show(Duration + " / " + CumDuration);` and its giving me the correct `CumDuration` including the posting in my `ListView` table below.

But if I removed the message, the result is coming like this:

```
+------------------+-----------------------+
| Message          | Duration              |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| Connection open  | 0.362 sec / 0.646 sec | //should be / 0.362 sec
+------------------+-----------------------+
| Session begun    | 0.284 sec / 0.646 sec |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| Connection close | 9.108 sec / 9.855 sec | //should be / 9.754 sec
+------------------+-----------------------+
| Session end      | 0.101 sec / 9.855 sec |
+------------------+-----------------------+
```

Given the multithreading that were used here, I suspect because of the really tight span of time between the connection and session, the CumDuration of connection was override by session at the posting level. When I used `MessageBox.Show()` my code was able to cope with the right CumDuration variable.

Here are the particular codes I'm looking at right now:

```
Duration = Math.Round(swDuration.Elapsed.TotalSeconds, 3);
CumDuration += Duration;
```

I am trying to use the `interlocked` method but I couldn't figure out how or where to put?

Or should I use another approach?

Comment: [Threading in C# - ADVANCED THREADING - Nonblocking Synchronization - Interlocked](https://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Interlocked) by ​Joseph Albahari.

Comment: Thanks, man! I've been hearing this name. I thought this was something else. I will look into this now.

Comment: It's unclear what trying to accomplish with the CumDuration variable based upon the question (i.e. single global StopWatch, local, or both - cum increment and duration).  If you post a copy of the code, I can definitely get it sorted for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you make `midpointCount` to keep number of milliseconds then it could be as simple as

```
Interlocked.Add(ref midpointCountMs, swDuration.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

Comment: Thank you for this man! But I'm still getting the same result. I created an `int` variable for `midpointCount` and `(int)swDuration.ElapsedMilliseconds`. Unless, I am doing it wrong.